# Workflow Xaml Custom Activity Versioning

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, workflow, workflow-foundation

We have a custom activity which we use in our .Net 3.5 State Workflows.

The xaml looks similar to this:

```
 <ns0:OurCustomActivity x:Name="workflow1" InProp1="{x:Null}"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
      xmlns:ns0="clr-namespace:Our.Custom.Activity;Assembly=Our.Custom.Activities,    
      Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=12345">
    ...
  </ns0:OurCustomActivity>
```

The activity dll has a strong name which the designer writes into namespace declaration in xaml file.

Now the problem is, we have hundreds of workflows using this custom activity and whenever we'd change the version of the custom activity assembly we'd have to rewrite the version in all the workflows.

As opposed to just recompile if we used .Designer.cs instead of XML.

Is there any way to overcome this other than not using XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [The Problem Solver's](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/) guides to versioning long running workflows to be very helpfull. He has 4 parts: [Part 1](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/09/10/versioning-long-running-workfows.aspx) [Part 2](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/09/11/versioning-long-running-workflows-part-2.aspx) [Part 3](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/09/16/versioning-long-running-workfows-part-3.aspx) [Part 4](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/09/22/versioning-long-running-workflows-part-4.aspx) where each one builds on the previous.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows can use the .Net versioning infrastructure- I'm not sure if this was in place back in 3.5 though. Here's an overview of the process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727506.aspx